# when(view.getWidth()).thenReturn(anyInt()) error its a stub with junit and powermock

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

i need to test some class and i need a View class and mock his getWidth method, for do this i mock a View.class and do
 `when(view.getWidth()).thenreturn(1)` 
but give me this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at android.view.View.getWidth(View.java:301)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Which jUnit are you using? Android doesn't really support jUnit4.

Comment: You have to use 'Roboelectric' framework to shadow the View implementation.

Comment: Im using junit4. Its not possible using only mockito?